# Syntax error, unrecognized expression when parsing tr element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a `$.post()` in jQuery and receiving a `<tr>` element in response that resembles this:

```
<tr class="editable" id="527a84eb-b430-4a33-9079-a19d00ca373c">
    <td class="date">2013-04-05
    </td>
    <td class="amountType">Credit
    </td>
    <td class="amount">$5.00
    </td>
    <td class="category">Meals
    </td>
    <td class="notes"></td>
    <td data-expense-report-line-item-id="527a84eb-b430-4a33-9079-a19d00ca373c" class="actionItems">
        <button class="deleteLineItem">Delete</button>
        <button class="editLineItem">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I plan on injecting this row in my table with this function:

```
$.post('@Url.Content("~/ExpenseReports/SaveLineItem")', {
    Date: date,
    Amount: amount,
    AmountType: amountType,
    ExpenseCategoryId: category,
    Notes: notes,
    ExpenseReportId: expenseReportId,
    ExpenseReportLineItemId: expenseReportLineItemId
}, function (data) {
    if ($('table tbody').length > 1) {
        $('table tbody tr:last').slideUp(200, function () {
            $(data).insertAfter('table tbody tr:first').slideDown();
        });
    } else {
        alert(data);
        $(data).appendTo($('table tbody'));
    }
    row.find('td.date:first input.date').val('');
    row.find('td.amount:first input.amount').val('');
    row.find('td.amountType:first select.amountType').val('Debit');
    row.find('td.category:first select.category').val('');
    row.find('td.notes:first input.notes').val('');
}, 'html');
```

The intent here is to insert this row after the first row in the `tbody` element.  However, when I try this, I get a javascript error back:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <tr class="editable" id="527a84eb-b430-4a33-9079-a19d00ca373c">
        <td class="date">
            2013-04-05
        </td>
        <td class="amountType">
            Credit
        </td>
        <td class="amount">
            $5.00
        </td>
        <td class="category">
            Meals
        </td>
        <td class="notes">

        </td>
        <td data-expense-report-line-item-id="527a84eb-b430-4a33-9079-a19d00ca373c" class="actionItems">
            <button class="deleteLineItem">Delete</button>
            <button class="editLineItem">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

It seems to me that this should be parseable by jQuery.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `<tr>`s can slide down, but that wouldn't be the problem you are finding

Comment: Using firebug right here (so whatever version of jQuery SO is using) it parses your html fine (ran `$('<tr> ..your stuff .. </tr>')` )

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if this is a Chrome issue...

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that shows your code working (mostly unmodified) http://jsfiddle.net/mUExf/

Comment: No, it's failing in FireFox for me too, with the same message.  I am using jquery 1.9.0, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @AlexW it can be either.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Here's a good read: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9

Comment: @AlexW I didn't think this was the problem but I changed the arguments to selectors and it does not seem to affect the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of jQuery 1.9, with 1.10.2 it works just good